# What was the poem that Thor was reciting while in the chamber with Korg?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

During the movie when he first meets Korg we see Thor still grieving the loss of his father. He is on his knees when he begins to quote a specific poem about the brave entering Valhalla. It seemed to be a poem that he'd possibly grew up reciting. As he was quoting it Loki then appears. What did Thor actually say in the poem?

Comment: Yes it was something along the lines of what you said "where the brave live forever"

Comment: I couldn't hear it very well but the first word is "Odin" and I heard the word Valhalla in there, but I couldn't make out much else. Also of note is that Thor is on his knees and speaking in a hushed tone. It is almost certainly a prayer to Odin, probably similar to what JohnP provided.

Comment: Okay, not an answer but I found something related, Stoic's Viking funeral in How To Train Your Dragon 2. It's very moving (if that's was your reason for wanting to know more), and you can take a look at the video if you like:

Answer (score 22):

Without having seen the movie, I suspect that the prayer Thor is reciting is one often attributed as a "Viking prayer for the dead" as follows:

> Lo, There do I see my Father, and
>   Lo, there do I see my Mother, and
>   Lo, There do I see my Brothers and my Sisters and
>   Lo, There do I see my people back to the begining, and
>   Lo they do call to me, and
>   Bid me take my place among them in the halls of Valhalla,
>   Where the brave will live forever.

Or a similar version:

> Lo, There do I see my Father
>   Lo, There do I see my Mother and
>   My Brothers and my Sisters
>   Lo, There do I see the line of my people back to the begining
>   Lo, They do call to me
>   They bid me take my place among them in the halls of Valhalla
>   Where thine enemies have been vanquished
>   Where the brave shall live Forever
>   Nor shall we mourn but rejoice for those that have died the glorious death

However, this was basically invented for the film [*The 13th Warrior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_13th_Warrior), which was an adaption of the Crichton book "[Eaters of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaters_of_the_Dead)". Here is the poem as it appears in the book:

> Lo, I see here my father and mother.
>   Lo, now I see all my deceased relatives sitting.
>   Lo, there is my master, who is sitting in Paradise.
>   Paradise is so beautiful, so green.
>   With him are his men and boys.
>   He calls to me, so bring me to him.

Now, Eaters is based partially on a truthful account, and partially on Beowulf. The poem as recorded by Ahmad ibn Fadlan (Who did actually travel north) is:

> Behold, I see my father and mother.
>   I see all my dead relatives seated.
>   I see my master seated in Paradise and Paradise is beautiful and green;
>   With him are men and boy servants.
>   He calls me.
>   Take me to him.

Additionally, this was not recited by a warrior, but by a slave girl before she was ritually executed following the death of her master. You can find a breakdown of this [at this website](http://radicalbritain.blogspot.com/2014/05/the-anglo-saxon-foundations-hilarious.html) with a few other links as well.

Comment: “Paradise is so beautiful, so green” — I *knew* the movie was actually a Thor/Hulk romantic comedy.

Answer (score 10):

**TLDR**

- JohnP deserves the credit...
- It is a modified version of the Viking Prayer.

It sounds like a modified version of the Viking Prayer as @JohnP stated initially. Here is the actual dialogue from the movie.

> **THOR:** *Odin, I bid you take your place in the halls of Valhalla...*
> (then:)
> *Where the brave shall live forever.   Nor shall we mourn but rejoice*
>
> **THOR:** (CONT’D) - *for those that have died the glorious death.*
> **LOKI** (O.S.) - *for those that have died the glorious death.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ragnarok: Draft Script](http://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/thor_ragnarok.pdf)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

So, since some of the characters' names came  from Norse Mythology,this prayer, or poem, is from Norse Mythology.

The majority goes like this:

> Lo, they do call to me, They bid me take my place among them In the Halls of Valhalla, Where the brave shall live forever, Where thine enemies have been vanquished, Nor shall we mourn but rejoice, For those who have died The glorious death.

This is the only thing I got from research, and I am merely 11 as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have a source for where in Norse myth this is said?